# Steady state of a $4 \times 4$ transition matrix

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, markov-process

Normally I just take $q(M_{m\times n} - I_{m\times n})$ to workout the steady state, but here I have:

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrr} 0 & 0 & .8 & .2 \\ .4 & .6 & 0 & 0 \\ .2 & .8 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & .7 & .3\end{array}\right).$$

I can't use my normal method for it would be excessive for this matrix, how can I solve problems like this with $4 \times 4$ transition matrices

edit: If I know $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} P^n$, can I use their values somehow?

Comment: Just to be sure, is the above matrix your transition matrix? If so, the easy thing might be to diagonalize it, take the $n$th power and then take the limit.

Comment: Yeah that is the transition matrix. I know $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} P^n = \frac{1}{30} * [7,14,7,2]$ where that single row of the matrix repeats for all four rows and that 1/30 multiplies to all values on all four rows.

Comment: Just to be sure, is the above matrix your transition matrix? If so, the easy thing might be to diagonalize it, take the $n$th power and then take the limit. Wolfram Alpha seems to suggest that your steady state is

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc} \frac{7}{30} & \frac{7}{15} & \frac{7}{30} & \frac{1}{15} \\ \frac{7}{30} & \frac{7}{15} & \frac{7}{30} & \frac{1}{15} \\ \frac{7}{30} & \frac{7}{15} & \frac{7}{30} & \frac{1}{15} \\ \frac{7}{30} & \frac{7}{15} & \frac{7}{30} & \frac{1}{15}\end{array}\right).$$

This more or less gives you your steady state. What am I missing?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Do you know what it means to calculate 'the limiting probability of success?' I assumed this meant to calculate the steady state?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Or am I taking some values from that steady state, specifically the ones in regard to success?

Comment: I think you need to give us a little more detail. I think calculating the steady state transition matrix is necessary but I think we are missing some initial data or context.

Comment: @CameronWilliams The rows and columns from the first transition matrix read sf,ss,fs,ff from left to right and top to bottom. These mean success and fail, and are in reference to the past two bids that a bidder has attempted. The probability of succeeding for example given that you had succeeded twice prior is 0.6 since this would be ss -> ss, and obviously ss going to another success is just ss as it only shows past two success or fail

Comment: So now I guess I just total the probabilities 7/30 + 7/15 to get a limited probability of success of 21/30?

Comment: @CameronWilliams because only fs and ss correspond to current successes and have therefore there is a 21/30 of getting a success out of the four potential scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to solve it your way. An equivalent way to solve it is by

$ V = V*\left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & .8 & .2 \\
.4 & .6 & 0 & 0 \\
.2 & .8 & 0 & 0\\ 
0  & 0  & .7& .3\end{array} \right] $, where $V = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc}a & b & c & d \end{array} \right] $ and then solving the resulting equations for $a, b, c, d$, with the fact that $a + b + c + d = 1$.

If you'll settle for a numerical answer you can always code this up. Ether way, the answer is $V = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc}.2333 & .4667 & .2333 & .0667 \end{array} \right]$.

Also, you can numerically find that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P^n =  \left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
.2333 & .4667 & .2333 & .0667 \\
.2333 & .4667 & .2333 & .0667 \\
.2333 & .4667 & .2333 & .0667\\ 
.2333 & .4667 & .2333 & .0667\end{array} \right] $